# Onclick function in a submit button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, plc

So this webpage is interacting with a Siemens PLC. There are three buttons: one to start the process; one to stop; and one to reset the entire thing. Everything works as expected, but the onclick function.

```
<img id="pic" src="Images/Status00.png" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px; height: 70px;"> 
<input type="submit" value="Start" style="height: 45px; width: 150px" id="start" onclick="changePic('green')">
<input type="hidden" name='"web2plc".start' value="1">
<input type="hidden" name='"web2plc".stop' value="0">
```

Script looks like this:

```
function changePic(color)
 {
     var imageSrc = document.getElementById("pic");
     if(color == "green")
     {
         imageSrc.src="Images/Status01.png";
     }
     else
     {
         imageSrc.src="Images/Status00.png";
     }
 }
```

I added two buttons just to check if it is working or not and it does.

```
<tr>
<td height="55px"><button onclick="changePic('green')">Green</button>
<button onclick="changePic('red')">Red</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

When I press the green/red button, it changes the image to the corresponding one defined in the function changePic(colour).

I am very new to designing webpages and have followed the manual provided by Siemens to get the basic functionality working. Please let me know if there is any mistake in the syntax or if I should be doing this differently.

Edit:

Images look like this:

1. [Status00.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trkwm.jpg)
2. [Status01.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB2on.jpg)
3. [Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvKqu.jpg)

Comment: change the type to button instead of submit

Comment: What is the difference between submit and button?

Comment: Are you sure the click event doesn't trigger? Try a console.log in the first line of your function.

Comment: Your code works as it is, only that your server sends a new page (reloads the current page) as a response to the form submission.

Comment: working fine for me :(

Comment: A submit button also triggers a form submit event in addition to your click event.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I am not sure. I will add the console.log and check it. Do I need to inspect the webpage when it is online?

Comment: You need to check the running site yes, (whether it's live or local running). Using console.log() to debug your code is a common way to find mistakes. You will use it a lot if you keep programming ;) If you have any troubles doing this, I will post a small example in the answers :)

Comment: If it's just plain HTML, you can open the HTML file in the browser and open the browser's developer tools screen. Go to the console tab and check if whenever you click on the button it returns something. You could also just add a plain alert (`alert("your text here")`), rather than using `console.log("your text here")`.

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean? As I said I can start and stop the process (hardware), but the only problem is that the images are not changing as expected.

Comment: Look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vgktzsob/). You can see the above code works fine.

Comment: Why you need submit button, if you are using action only on front end

Comment: Please clear what you want to achieve !!!

Comment: @Wimanicesir  Thank you. I will try this and edit the post if it works.

Comment: @DupinderSingh That's how I can write to the variables in my PLC. What is want to achieve is: depending upon the button pressed the images should change. For example, when the start button is pressed a green circle (image) is displayed and when the stop button is pressed a red circle (image) is displayed.

Comment: @nAviD By changing the type to the button, I can switch between the images, but I lose values of 1 and 0 are being written to my PLC variables.

Comment: Please rearead my comment, you're loading a new page, that's why you can't see the images changing. Take a look at the documentation of [`input type="submit"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit).

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick on the button works fine. We are just missing the image element to make your code work.

You defined: `var imageSrc = document.getElementById("pic");`

So based on that I added the following HTML element: `<img id="pic" src="https://i.imgur.com/wBDM0LM.png" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px; height: 70px;">`

See below for a working example:

```js
function changePic(color)
{
  var imageSrc = document.getElementById("pic");
  if(color == "green")
  {
    imageSrc.src="https://i.imgur.com/wBDM0LM.png.png";
  }
  else
  {
    imageSrc.src="https://i.imgur.com/ShlKo5C.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Start" style="height: 45px; width: 150px" id="start" onclick="changePic('green')">
<button onclick="changePic('red')" style="height: 45px; width: 150px">Red</button>
<input type="hidden" name='"web2plc".start' value="1">
<input type="hidden" name='"web2plc".stop' value="0">

<img id="pic" src="https://i.imgur.com/ShlKo5C.png" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px; height: 70px;">
```

Comment: <img id="pic" src="Images/Status00.png" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px; height: 70px;">

Comment: I have also added images for reference in the edit section. Please take a look.

Comment: I added some of your information to make fiddle work accordingly. @Stoner

Comment: So by default Status00.png image (i.e, red one) will be displayed and when the start button is clicked it will change to Status01.png.

Comment: You defined the green image to represent the `status00.png` so this is what I did. Or would you like to see it reversed rather than how it works now? I reversed it so you can see the end result @Stoner

Comment: By changing the input type from submit to button type works. However, the values 1 and 0 are not being written to my PLC variables and my process doesn't start or stop.

Comment: Code above is only working for front-end purpose. If you need more functionality, then please share with me what language you are using for the back-end and what code you are already using to try to make things work.

Comment: I am using Ladder logic. If that's relevant I can share it.

Comment: To make it more clear I have added how the webpage looks in the edit.

Comment: You are stating "this webpage is interacting with a Siemens PLC". What programming language or API are you using to make communication between the two happen? I am not familiar with Ladder Logic so I do not know if this even is supposed to be a programming language able to support web back-end architecture.

Comment: It is interacting using Profinet communication protocol. So the PLC assigns an IP address to the webpage (these webpages are converted and stored in something similar to a database) and using that it can be accessed over the internet. Thanks for all the inputs. Hopefully, I will be able to figure it out with the help I have gotten here :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

I used Jquery

but its working fine

```js
$('.button').click(function(){

 if($('#light').hasClass('start'))
  {
    $('#light').removeClass("start");
    $('#light').addClass("stop");
  }
  else if($('#light').hasClass('stop'))
  {
    $('#light').removeClass("stop");
    $('#light').addClass("start");
  }
 

})
```

```css
#light{
  width : 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius:15px;
}
div.start{
  background-color: green;
}

div.stop{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='button start'>Button</button>

<div class='start' id='light' >
  
</div>
```